# Help me improve the question which already has a re producable example

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Only buzzing sound while playing wav file through QAudioOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915603/only-buzzing-sound-while-playing-wav-file-through-qaudiooutput)

It has got two downvotes. I have written a reproducible example. I have mentioned in comments that it isn't about a particular `wav` file. I have tried this with an `mp3` file also and failed.

What should I go more to get positive attention to this?

Comment: Seems to me so far nobody else has actually succeeded in reproducing. Have you reproduced it on another machine yourself?

Comment: @Gimby I today tried it on Windows 7 laptop with Qt 5.5.1 with an mp3 file. still the buzzing sound is all that I can hear.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius with the exact snippet you've given in your question? You comment that it doesn't seem to be an issue in your code, so maybe SO can't help you with it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was just my guess. read my latest comments on that question.

Comment: "I have mentioned in comments..." Edit your question with all relevant information. Comments may not last, and people don't always read them all before commenting or answering. Also, avoid using pictures for text...